# Scroll to a Div in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I was trying to create the similar jquery scroll functionality to scroll to a `DIV` when pressed a button but didn't find any good solution to do that in KnockoutJS.
Could you please suggest any approach?

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#myDivWhereToBeScrolled').offset().top }, 1000);
```

Comment: either you can call a function on click handler and call the animate there. or you can create custom directives.

Comment: Yes, i was trying to  add this code on my click handler but doesn't work  $('#listOfDebtors').animate({ scrollTop: 5000 }, 3000);

Comment: you need to call a function and then nee to call..

Comment: not sure what did u mean?
here is my scenario.
i would like to scroll that DIV when i pressed a button and then come into this function
 `function addRow(){
       $('#listOfDebtors').animate({ scrollTop: 5000 }, 3000);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process was correct but my project setting was somehow different and thus it was scrolling the wrong element.
Found the correct css element to be scrolled and worked like this

```
$('.goportal-content-scroll').scrollTop(0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you need to call a function in your model and from there you need to add your code, something like

```
 <button data-bind="click: yourFunction">Scroll</button>
```

and in your model

```
this.yourFunction = function(){
               $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#myDivWhereToBeScrolled').offset().top }, 1000);
           }
```

let me know is that you need.

i have created a plunkr, please have a look http://plnkr.co/edit/J0dGlzJT8sr2PJ0U83FS?p=preview

Comment: Yes my requirement and scenario is same 
I have a binding with a button 
and from that function i am calling this but still doesn't work

`<button id="addToDebtorListBtn" type="button" class="form-control btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-bind="click:$root.addDebtorToOrder, visible:!isOpenedForUpdate">{{$addDebtor}}</button>`
    
`    function addDebtorToOrder(){
 $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#listOfDebtors').offset().top }, 1000);
}`

Comment: i have added scrollTop to 500 for demonstration

Comment: I was following the plunkr and its pretty straightforward but still i have some problem.    
I was also using `$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 700 }, 3000);` and seems like it's working when i first time pressed the click but after that it doesn't work.    
another thing is that `var test = $('#listOfDebtors').offset().top;` Here i am getting test = 0

Comment: second time it will not work since the scrollTop is already  700, no scrolling.. $('#listOfDebtors').offset().top is zero because its offest is zero. try adding margin-top and check the value

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/J0dGlzJT8sr2PJ0U83FS?p=preview  plnkr updated with   div offset calculation and reset

Comment: @Mofizur create a fiddle then.

Comment: As i see, now it scrolls but it doesn't scroll the page, it scrolls the windows. create some white space after the page